# Is there a way to take an in-browser screenshot and send it in chat attachment as the bot | discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a command like `$screenshot` and the bot will then send a screenshot of something on a website. I haven't found a way to actually take screenshots so I'm hoping someone here will help me out.

Comment: Here's a related article to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

Can use selenium to generate a screenshot of a website.

```java
  public static void screenshot(WebDriver driver, String imageName) throws Exception{
        new File(imageName).getParentFile().mkdirs();
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        Files.copy(screenshot, new File(imageName));
    }
```

selenium for javascript: [node selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)
can also use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

Comment: As the OP's tags are both `javascript` related, how is this going to help?